# Why does my while loop not work for counting the sum of an array and displaying the array

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I am attempting to display a random array whilst also displaying the sum of that array yet I can't get it to work, I know how to do it with a for loop but I was instructed on doing a while loop instead, any ideas?

```
 private void SumOfArray() {
        myWindow.clearOut();
        int total = 0;
        int[] a = new int[4];
        int i;
        i = 0;
        while (i < a.length) {
            i++;
            a[i] = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        }
        i = 0;
        while (i < a.length) {
            i++;
             myWindow.writeOutLine(a[i]);
        }
        while (i < a.length) {
            total += a[i];
        i++;

        }
        myWindow.writeOutLine(total);

    }
```

Comment: What does the output give you?  What were you expecting instead?  I know this problem is simple but it's good to be specific and say exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are incrementing `i` prematurely, causing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You should increment it after assigning a number of `a[i]`.

Change it to

```
    while (i < a.length) {
        a[i] = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        i++;
    }
```

Now the loop behaves similar to a for loop - i.e. `i` is incremented after all the other statements of the loop's body.

Your other loops should also be fixed, and in fact, all your loops can be merged into a single loop :

```
    int i = 0;
    while (i < a.length) {
         a[i] = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
         myWindow.writeOutLine(a[i]);
         total += a[i];
         i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition, You have 3 while loops and two times where you assign `0` to `i` ....